# How to understand PHP syntax errors?

Tags: php, command-line, syntax, interpreter

I'm quite new to using PHP but this has been stumping me for a while now. Here is my test.php

```
<?PHP

$db = 'str1';
$sql = 'str2';
$cat = $sql . $db
echo $cat
?>
```

First, when i run php test.php, i get no output. i now know that i am missing a semi-colon or 2 here.  It would be nice if php told me which line the syntax error was on.  The best i can get is to run php -l which indicates that there is a syntax error at all. But it seems like i could get more info?  Any idea how?

Comment: If you develop with error reporting displayed on screen, it will tell you the line numbers where it encounters errors. In cases like these, the error will be reported on the line _after_ the missing `;`.  `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`  Be sure to turn off display_errors when you put your code into production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `;` in the last 2 line that is why you are having errors. To see this errors make sure that `error_reporting` is on in your PHP configuration

Example

```
<?PHP
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $db = 'str1';
    $sql = 'str2';
    $cat = $sql . $db ;
    echo $cat ;
?>
```

Comment: The OP already knew the `;` was missing.

Comment: it's set to: error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED in php.ini. seems correct, no?

Comment: @glutz Why  do you want to exclude depreciated errors  ???

Comment: i dont.  that's just the default setting.  either way, i dont get errors reported.  Does the error_reporting() call override what is set in php.ini?

Comment: apparently, display_errors was off in php.ini. weird.

Comment: it looks like the problem was display_errors being off. even i now set error_reporting(0), i still get errors. but thanks for leading me down the right path!

Answer (score 0):

PHP cannot tell you things as specific as that however it can tell on what line you have something wrong.

If you are not seeing these sort of errors it is likely that your error_reporting is hiding these errors.

In your PHP ini you can set:

- `display_errors` to `1`
- `html_errors` to `1`
- `error_reporting` to `E_ALL`

It will tell you when it can't parse a line right but it won't specifically tell you what is wrong with that line like:

```
OMFG it's missing a semicolon
```

That being said it can tell you other specific things like:

- When a file does not exist
- When vars are not defined
- When a class does not exist

And other things, but no, last time I checked syntax errors are just reported as exactly that.